# debugging javascript in HTML5 using chrome web developer tools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

To be able to debug javascript on Eclipse directly in HTML5 code/libraries, I downloaded the ChromeWebdeveloper tools  and installed it on Eclipse. Also ran \chrome.exe --remote-shell-port= to run the debug on port 9222 on chrome.
However when I try to launch the application it shows me - "Failed to connect to the remote browser" - connect time out error.

Any clue whats going wrong in here?

Thanks

Comment: What's the advantage of debugging in Eclipse instead of in Chrome directly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already have Chrome.

Chrome comes with a *very nice* debugger already built in!

Just press `CTRL + SHIFT + J` to start it up, then click on `Sources`:

[image: chrome debugger]

Comment: +1 This is 50 times easier than trying to get some other debugger to work with Chrome